# QQuickView child of QtWidget window

Tags: c++, qml, qt-creator, qtwidgets

I am trying to to create a QQuickView sub-window that is embedded inside of an existing QWidget window. The below code I have creates a new separate QQuickView window instead of a sub-window.

main.cpp

```
subWindow::subWindow(QWidget* parent) {
    QQuickView* view = new QQuickView();
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view->show(); 
}
```

subWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    subWindow* sw = new subWindow();
    QWidget *sub = QWidget::createWindowContainer(sw, this);
    sub->setMinimumSize(1061, 511);
    sub->setMaximumSize(1061, 511);
    sub->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
    ui->subVerticalLayout->addWidget(sub);
}
```

Comment: whats is the problem?

Comment: When the application is run two separate windows display. I want the sub-window to display inside of the Main Window like a widget.

Comment: subWindow or MainWindow?

Comment: Do you compile the code?

Comment: what class does subWindow inherit from?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a `QWidget` based on a `QML`, then better use a `QQuickWidget`, to do so add:

```
QT += quickwidgets
```

to your .pro

and in the end you only use the following:

```
QQuickWidget *sub = new QQuickWidget();
sub->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
sub->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
sub->setMinimumSize(1061, 511);
sub->setMaximumSize(1061, 511);
sub->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
ui->subVerticalLayout->addWidget(sub);
```